# Restoring consumable products (coins) in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, in-app-purchase, icloud, cloudkit

I am building some quiz with consumable coins to use. I used NSUserDefault to save coins on device and its working. I am also using CloudKit for data in qiuz.

No trouble is how to restore coins if user switch device? There is a part solution with keychain but it only works on same device.

Is there way to store coins via dashboard in cloudkit with my data?

thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to use key-value storage in iCloud. It works almost the same way as NSUserDefaults, so you can switch totally to 'key-value storage' instead of NSUserDefaults.

["Designing for Key-Value Data in iCloud" by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html)

As well as NSUserDefaults 'key-value storage' allow developers to save simple data types, yet saved data is available across user devices with enabled iCloud.

**First step**: enable 'key-value storage' in application's Capabilities settings
[image: **enter image description here**]

**Second step**: on application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: implement subscription to  NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification notification at NSNotificationCenter.

**Third step**: write and read data to NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore() the same way you do it with NSUserDefaults.

Consider a way to resolve Key-Value Conflicts (in case user simaltaneously uses two or more devices, or one of the devices hadn't internet connection, etc)

Also, there is a limit on amount of data saved in Key-Value storage, number of keys, length of keys' names... Check the above link to Apple's Guide.